# Handling OTP response manipulation in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js

I have added functionality like 2FA on login screen using react when you login which is optional, which you can enable/disable, backend(express) API will check 2FA enable first and than send OTP to email and in the next screen it'll ask for to enter that OTP.

```
POST /login {"email" : "email@demo.com", "password":"hashedpassword"}
```

this /login api will send otp to specified email if entered credentials are correct.

in the next screen on react it'll ask for the same OTP as verification. and otp verification api looks like this

```
POST /verifyAndLogin {"email" : "email@demo.com","password":"hashedpassword","otp":"123123"}
```

and in the response i'm sending that entered OTP is correct or not, based on the correct credentials.

Successful otp validation response

```
200 {
  success: true,
  redirect: true,
  message:"Successfully logged in",
  token: "jwt token"
 }
```

Wrong OTP validation response

```
 200 {
      success: false,
      redirect: false,
      message:"invalid OTP"
     }
```

but recently i found that there is vulnerability to bypass this OTP validation using Response manipulation.
so how to handle it properly that prevents this bypass using response manipulation on react js and express js.

using Burpsuit tool i'm intercepting the specified apis which is responsible for validating OTP API, after intercepting and modifying the the api response of wrong otp, I'm able to log in with the same account.

Comment: But your server should not accept the modified token? maybe the ui can show you are logged in but the server shouldn't give any data.

Comment: @kennarddh  That is true but success response contains some additional data as well, if you put valid JWT token from some other account responses, you'll be able to access data from server.

Comment: Yeah that's called other people account stealing... you cant prevent it. maybe you can with refresh token and short time token like 1 min or 30 sec. i dont know how can the hacker get other user token but you can store the token local storage but the expire time is just 30 sec. you also have token in cookie that live longer like 3 months. then every token expired you need to refresh by calling api and the api will return new token and refresh token. so even if the hacker can do xss (which you should fix the xss problem too) too they will only get the 30 sec token.. cant prevent everything.

Answer (score 0):

If JWT is implemented correctly at server side, and OTP is required to get the token - you should not care about response manipulation.

As @milind-modi mention, getting token of other account will give the user access to this specific account, it has nothing to do with OTP.